# How to tell whether elaboration has completed at a breakpoint?

Tags: systemc, vlab

When I hit a breakpoint in a VLAB script, how can I find out if I have caused elaboration to finish or not, yet?

My script reaches a statement that raises an error:

`Error: (E529) insert module failed: elaboration done`

(The command that causes this is `vlab.instantiate("stim", "stim")`)

So obviously elaboration was unexpectedly (for me) already completed. I need to somehow go back in the process and find out where that happened - so I need some way of asking "is elaboration complete?" at the point where I set breakpoints earlier in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SystemC provides the following function to query the current phase of elaboration or simulation.

```cpp
sc_status sc_get_status();
```

It returns either `SC_ELABORATION`, `SC_BEFORE_END_OF_ELABORATION`, `SC_END_OF_ELABORATION`, `SC_START_OF_SIMULATION`, `SC_RUNNING`, `SC_PAUSED`, `SC_STOPPED`, or `SC_END_OF_SIMULATION`.

See section 4.5.8 in the SystemC Language Reference Manual for more details. Note that this function was only added in the most recent version of the standard, [IEEE Standard 1666-2011](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1666/download/1666-2011.pdf).

In VLAB, the SystemC API is available from the `sysc` Python package, so the following script can be used to test if the current phase is at elaboration:

```py
import sysc
print "Is elaboration phase:", sysc.sc_get_status() == sysc.SC_ELABORATION
```